# Google Foobar Challenge, One Test Case Failing

Tags: python

Yesterday I was lucky enough to be invited to take the Google Foobar challenge. I'm on the second challenge, and within the first half hour of working on it I had what I thought was a working solution. However, it's failing one of the hidden test cases, even though through all my tests it's working fine and I have no idea what the problem might be.

For the challenge, I'm to write a function that, given a list 'l' and an integer 't', determines the first contiguous sublist within l where the numbers within that sublist add up to 't'. The function outputs a list containing the start and end positions of that sublist. For example, given the list [4, 3, 5, 7, 8] and the int 12, it would find the sublist [4, 3, 5] and output [0, 2]. If no such sublist exists, it return [-1, -1].

This is the solution I've come up with (using Python 2.7):

```
def solution(l, t):
    for item in l:
        index = l.index(item)
        output = [index]
        total = 0
        while total < t and index < len(l):
            total += l[index]
            index += 1
        if total == t:
            output.append(index - 1)
            return output
    return [-1, -1]
```

This passes 4 out of 5 test cases, but I don't have a way to tell why the last case fails. I've been able to determine through rigorous testing (about 3 hours worth) that the case has a list of length 100 and contains at least one 100 within the list, both of which are maximum amounts based on standards I was given for what could be input. Those standards are:

- Each list l will contain at least 1 element but never more than 100.
- Each element of l will be between 1 and 100.
- t will be a positive integer, not exceeding 250.
- The first element of the list l has index 0.
- For the list returned by solution(l, t), the start index must be equal or smaller than the end index.

If anyone can think of a reason why that test case is failing, I would be very grateful. I don't know if I'll be able to make it through the whole challenge, but I've been having a lot of fun with it so far and really don't want it to end this soon. I have 2 days and 15 hours left to complete it as of posting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here about what `lst.index(elem)` does. It's a search algorithm that inspects every element from the beginning of the list to the end, one by one, and returns the index of the first instance of `elem` that it finds. As such, if you have the input `[1, 2, 11, 1, 4, 5]` and your target is 10, you'll always get 0 as your index for any calls to `l.index(1)`. This precludes the possibility of visiting the `[1, 4, 5]` sublist which is the correct answer.

The solution to the problem is to use `enumerate` to return tuples of `(index, element)` pairs from the iterable:

```
for item in l:
    index = l.index(item)
```

becomes

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    # do your thing
```

Beyond that, the algorithm isn't terribly fast and it doesn't handle negative numbers, but it should be acceptable given the extremely mild requirements, so I'm betting this bug is enough to fix the problem.